# Avoiding OptimisticLockException in JEE JSF web apps using JPA where multiple commits are possible within the same view

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, concurrency, version

Working with JEE and JPA, using Optimistic locking with @Version within a web application, is there a recommended approach for dealing with updates (entityManager#merge), if the same user can make multiple commits of different sets of entity objects within the same view, including updating the same entity object more than once?

The issue being entityManager#merge does not update the version number in the memory object it received, but rather returns a new object that should be used in the future if merging again. This means if there are complex relationships in memory, all have to be updated with this new object. Else, the next time a merge is attempted from the same view, an OptimisticLockException will be thrown.

Rather than having to traverse through the view's model and update every instance of a merged object (which opens the door to high risk of runtime errors), one option will be to ensure no partial work is allowed in the view, then always rebuilding the view's model after every update. This seems rather primitive and non-performing. Wondering if there are any other recommended approaches. Thanks!

Here is an example scenario:

User "Manager" has a list of "Employees" in her web view. "Manager" selects an "Employee" and changes their phone number and saves. Manager realizes she had the phone number wrong, corrects it, and saves again within the same view (JSF) or web session.

The web view maintained a list of Employees, which is needed to do a selection. After the first update, without refetching of that list from DB, or updating the list in-memory, the new entity version number will not propagate to the view causing an OptimisticLockException on the second save. Is there another option other than refetch the list after 1st merge, update in memory after 1st merge, or find-before-every-merge merge memory object into found object, then commit?

Comment: So if you create a multithreaded unitest without JSF, it works?

Comment: @Kukeltje no, that wouldn't get past the challenge. It's not a JSF issue, but JPA dependent. Any client executing multiple merges will face the same challenge.

Comment: then please remove the jsf tag

Comment: I think it is valuable as it is part of the scenario.

Comment: no, it is not. Tags are for what is an integral part of the problem.

Comment: @Kukeltje so do you have any thoughts on approaches to this problem?

Comment: em.merge returns the updated entity. Just put it back in list.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for chiming in, and thanks for all of your online contributions! I've used many of them in the past. THANK YOU! What you suggest is one of the approaches I mentioned, and the one we are currently using, but like I mentioned, it creates lots of opportunity for runtime errors with more complex data graphs and deeper relationships, or where entity objects go through multiple business tier methods as part of their processing and em.merge happening in the bus tier. Is there another solution?